# Regular expressions for Venezuelan phone numbers not matching as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this two RegEx:

```
Local Numbers: /^0058|\+58(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789]))\d{7}$/
Mobile Numbers: /^0058|\+58(?:4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7}$/
```

The idea is to validate Venezuelan phone numbers adding the prefix for the country. Right now, values like this are valid:

```
00584129999999
04129999999
04249999999
00584249999999
02129999999
00582129999999
```

But values likes this:

```
+584129999999
+582129999999
```

aren't. I'm not able to find where I'm making a mistake, so any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the alternation operator `|` is larger than you think. Your first regex separates into

```
^0058
|
\+58(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789]))\d{7}$
```

Also, you should allow a single `0` as well (instead of making the `+58` or `0058` mandatory).

You probably wanted something like

```
^(?:(?:00|\+)58|0)(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789]))\d{7}$
```

and if you want to merge the two regexes into one, no problem:

```
^(?:(?:00|\+)58|0)(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789])|4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7}$
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lS3rZ0/1).